# Listview onItemClickListener not executed

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm lost, I can not see why the OnItemClickListener is not executed when i click on a item in the listview. I tried to add android:focusable="false" to both the listview and the textview's. Thanks for any help.

```
     clistArray = new ArrayList<CustomerList>();
     clistDataAdapter = new CustomerListAdapter(this, R.layout.cus_list, clistArray);
 CustView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.allCustomerList);

     OnItemClickListener cuslistener = new OnItemClickListener (){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                   selectedCustomer = cusdatasource.getCustomer(String.valueOf(id));      
              }
      }

     CustView.setAdapter(clistDataAdapter);
     CustView.setOnItemClickListener(cuslistener);
     CustView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

Listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="False">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/allCustomerList"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</ListView>
```

cus_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/clistStop"
    style="@style/WhiteSText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/black"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:text="123" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/clistName"
    style="@style/WhiteSText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/black"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="name kkkkk" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/clistCheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/black"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because checkBox is clickable and listItem is also clickable, so here, checkBox takes the focus and hence listItem cannot be clicked.

You just need to set :

Set all items `focusable="false"` of listItem.

Comment: I fault I had added the focusable="false" to everything but the checkBox, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property of checkbox 1.Focusable = false and 2.FocusableInTouchMode = false.It will work...